# How to Compose 2 JSON Lenses Alongside Each Other?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson, lenses

**TL;DR** Lenses are confusing and here I track an effort to compose lenses "horizontally". There's 1 solution using `to`, and questions on why `Getter` and `alongside` don't work.

---

Lenses compose nicely in a "vertical" sense using `(.)`, which allows you to stack lenses that drill into an object.

But what if in 1 traversal of on object, you'd like 2 lenses to act on the same leaf nodes, and extract a product, say, a tuple?

For example, you have some JSON:

```
[ {"a":1, "b":11},
  {"a":2, "b":22},
  {"a":3, "b":33}]
```

And you'd like to write a function to extract values at `"a"` and `"b"` into tuples:

```
ex :: [(Int, Int)]
ex = [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33)]
```

## One Solution

After great lengths, I found I could do this using `to`, and all the following permutations are equivalent (I think):

```
text :: Text
text = "[{\"a\":1, \"b\":11}, {\"a\":2, \"b\":22}, {\"a\":3, \"b\":33}]"

num0, num1, num2, num3 :: [(Maybe Integer, Maybe Integer)]
num0 = text ^.. _Array . each      . to (\o -> (o ^? key "a" . _Integer, o ^? key "b" . _Integer))
num1 = text ^.. values             . to (\o -> (o ^? key "a" . _Integer, o ^? key "b" . _Integer))
num2 = text ^.. _Array . traverse  . to (\o -> (o ^? key "a" . _Integer, o ^? key "b" . _Integer))
num3 = text ^.. _Array . traversed . to (\o -> (o ^? key "a" . _Integer, o ^? key "b" . _Integer))
```

(Note if you try for `[(Int, Int)]` instead of the above `Maybe` version, you'll get some confusing error messages about `There's no monoid instance for Integer`. That makes sense.)

This answer is disappointing since it requires `to` over a lambda that extracts lenses separately, and packages them into a tuple separately. It'd be nice if some combinators allowed me to compose this directly.

## Why doesn't `Getter` work?

Based on examples and documentation, `Getter` sounds like exactly what I want:

```
num4 :: [(Integer, Integer)]
num4 = text ^.. values
       . runGetter  ((,)
                     <$> Getter (key "a" . _Integer)
                     <*> Getter (key "b" . _Integer))
```

But alas, I get an error message:

```
Could not deduce (Applicative f) arising from a use of 'key'
```

The [`f` in question](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Traversal) is existentially quantified (or... is it, since it's a type synonym), so, does that make it
incompatible with 'Getter'? Or...?

## Why doesn't `alongside` work?

[`alongside`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1.1/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v:alongside) also sounds like it should work, but again, no luck.

```
num5 :: [(Integer, Integer)]
num5 = text ^.. values . alongside (key "a" . _Integer) (key "b" . _Integer)
```

I couldn't figure that error out either

```
Couldn't match type `(t0, t'0)` with `Value`
```

Comment: @josh-f u can use `Fold` like `num4 = text ^.. values . runFold  ((,) <$> Fold (key "a" . _Integer) <*> Fold (key "b" . _Integer))`

Comment: unfortunately I can't add this as an answer because this is flagged as a duplicate, but while answers to the linked question are correct that such a function would be unsound, I'm fairly sure the "correct unsound" function to use is `lensProduct` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1.1/docs/Control-Lens-Unsound.html#v:lensProduct